# Открытие  несколких ссылок  одним  кликом  по кнопке.

Tags: javascript, html, php

Приветствую, есть кнопка  выполняющие  действие нужно реализовать чтоб по ее  нажатию в добавок  открывалось несколько ссылок в  новых вкладках но пользователь оставался на   сайте. Искал по форумам не  нашел..
Есть кнопка

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Get reward!">
```

есть скрипт

```
<!-- MBT MULTIPLE LINKS CODE --> 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    function links() { 
    var http = "http://sh.st22/fv2129u"; 
    var win1 = window.open(http); 
    var http = "http://sh.st22/fX523jF"; 
    var win1 = window.open(http); 
    var http = "http://sh.st22/f1X54YP"; 
    var win1 = window.open(http); 
    var http = "http://sh.st22/fX495Pm"; 
    var win1 = window.open(http);  
    }
</script>
```

но он работает только на  элемент вида:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="javascript:links()">Текст</a>
```

как  мне  сделать чтоб он работал для:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Get reward!">
```

Comment: Используйте [MouseEvent][1] если на чистом Javascript, или jQuery.trigger, если подключена jQuery
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

Comment: вашши пользователи будут вспоминать вас довольно неблагодарными словами

Answer (score 1):

Вообще вот так, но все равно не во всех поддерживается. Как открывать и открывать ли решают настройки браузера.

```
function newTab(src) {
if($.browser.mozilla||$.browser.msie){
  window.open(src,'_blank');
}else{
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = src;
    a.target = "_blank";
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
}  
function links(){
var links = [ "http://sh.st22/fv2129u","http://sh.st22/fX523jF"];
for(i=0;i<links.length;i++){
newTab(links[i]);
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Это не подойдет](http://learn.javascript.ru/window-open)?

UP:
`<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Get reward!" onclick="links();return false;">` не подойдет?

Comment: Действия  не  происходит